# pass variable inner function to other function on model

Tags: php

I tried to pass variable to function to another function in my class like this.

```
public function test($id){
    Test::test2(function($id2){
        return $id2;
    });
}
```

I tried to rename the variable but I don't have a clue how to pass to `Test2` function variable from `test()`. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be looking for a closure:

```
Test::test2(function() use($id){
    return $id;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i will accept your answer, i can't add rep so i only can say thanks ;)

Comment: No problem, glad i could help you